# How can I prototype a very abstract theoretical framework?

Tags: programming-languages, architecture, theory, prototyping

I've had an idea for a semantic model of computing that's theoretically sound but is also quite unusual. I'd like to quickly prototype a system to prove that it can work in practice. Most of my work is in programming languages, so I'm comfortable putting together a small language for the purposes of testing, but I wonder if this is the best approach, as it necessitates a certain amount of advance work on the linguistic side that's not directly related to the computational model.

So what is the best prototyping strategy for a very high-level theoretical framework such as this? Should I go with a new language, or an embedded DSL, or some other approach? I can provide a bit more background if necessary, but this doesn't need to turn into a discussion of the specifics of the model.

Comment: With the little information given, the answer is 42.

Comment: Which functionality will you need in the prototype to prove that the idea has enough merit to be implemented fully.

Comment: @ammoQ: I was uncertain of how to phrase my question. Could you suggest some more information I might add?

Comment: @blueberryfields: Basically, I need to prove that it's possible to implement with good performance on real hardware, and test its capabilities with respect to different classes of algorithms.

Comment: Well, should your idea become reality, there will be a new *something*. If the *something* is (or contains) hardware, you need a hardware simulation to prove its viability. It the *something* is software based, you will need to implement the core of it.

Comment: @ammoQ: Right. My thinking, though, is that such a "hardware simulation" *is* a virtual machine, which requires a language of some kind to program for. The question is which will be faster: fighting to create a DSL in a language whose semantics are based on a different model, or fighting to make a *language* whose semantics match this one. They're two different expressions of the same problem, really.

Comment: In my understanding, the hardware simulation is controlled by machine code (the same machine code that would be run on the real silicone once it is built); it could be hand-written or generated by an assembler or compiler. I fail to see where a DSL comes into play, because such a language is located several abstraction layers higher.

Answer (score 1):

Try with an embedded DSL first. Maybe you don't need a whole new language. If you do, working with the DSL will quickly hurt, allowing you to learn that you do in fact need a whole new language.